# What is best practice for using E4 dependency injection for our own objects?

Tags: eclipse, dependency-injection, e4

I am working on an E4 RCP application and, while our basic DI configuration is working, I have some reservations about our current implementation.

1. The IInjector interface and @ProcessAdditions annotation are tagged as being discouraged for external access. Currently, we are using a series of statements similar to

   ```
   injector.addBinding(IInterface.class).implementedBy(Concrete.class);
   ```

   from within a method marked as @ProcessAdditions. What method(s) can be used that don't violate access rules? I know I can bind classes/strings to instances via IEclipseContext, but using ContextInjectionFactory by hand seems to force order of construction to be known by configurer (as opposed to other DI frameworks).
2. I know Guice has the concept of child injectors, but in E4, ContextInjectionFactory is internally set to use only the default injector for manufacturing. What is the best method to manufacture a group of objects, using DI, and subsequently disposing of this group? I would like to create a fresh batch of processing objects for each processing operation.

Answer (score 1):

`ContextInjectionFactory` is the only thing I have seen described for doing injection in e4 (in Lars Vogel's 'Eclipse 4 RCP' book for example). This is what I use in my e4 applications.

Some things, such as `@ProcessAdditions` are marked as discouraged because that part of the e4 API has not been finalized yet and might change, they can still be used. `@ProcessAdditions` is only used for the application Life Cycle class.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I was able to write some helper classes that do some cool stuff, but it is imperfect because of the hardcoded single "default" injector. It is usable, but not as elegant as Guice's support of child injectors, and since there is no IInjector.getBinding() or similar call, you can inadvertently overwrite a binding used by another context.

Comment: You are also unable to manually restore the injector bindings after overwriting them, so it's a bit dodgy.